# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#

hi ive got this error when i tried to run but theres error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDateOfDelivery", po.dateOfDelivery);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStatus", po.status);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDeliveryTiming", po.deliveryTiming);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCoID", po.coID);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    int iResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (iResult > 0)
                    {
                        result = "You have successfully updated the DeliveryOrder!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "You have encountered an error. Please try again.";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    result = "You have encountered an error. Please try again";
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the definition of your method.. I bet that it says it's returning an int, but you return `result` which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

One of your parameters is expecting an `int` type but you are passing `string` type.
Try below to convert string to int before passing.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCoID", Int32.Parse(po.coID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToInt32` method to convert your **string** variables to **integer**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCoID",Convert.ToInt32(po.coID));
```

Comment: The error is complaining about the opposite conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `cmd.Parameters.Add()` So that you can specify the expecting Datatype;

The DataType of the parameter will be [`OdbcType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctype(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using `OdbcCommands` and are of [`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using `SqlCommand`. In short the datatype will be depand on the type of command. here is an example with `SqlDbType`.

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.Int).Value = po.coID;
```

Make sure that `po.coID` is of integer type. or else you need to convert it to an integer; I would like to suggest [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) for this conversion